ERROR NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for n! using Angular 18 Standalone
I'm trying to connect my web app to Azure AD. When I deploy it doesn't show me the login. And I get the error in the console:
main-G2LTX4LO.js:14 ERROR
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for n!
at Ru.get (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:1135) at ec.get (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:10733) at ec.get (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:10733) at ec.get (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:10733) at Rg.get (main-G2LTX4LO.js :14:63453) at Vw (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:22071) at Bw (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:22311) at K (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:41655) at n.ɵfac [as factory] (main-G2LTX4LO.js:42:31311) at zo (main-G2LTX4LO.js:14:23511)
The examples I find use the app.module however I am NOT using app.module because I am using Standalone components with Angular version 18.
app.config.ts
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { OAuthModule, OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    importProvidersFrom(
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      OAuthModule.forRoot(),
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient]
        }
      })
    ),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    OAuthService
  ]
};

auth.config.ts
import { AuthConfig } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
 
export const authConfig: AuthConfig = {
 
  // Url of the Identity Provider
  issuer: 'secret',
 
  // URL of the SPA to redirect the user to after login
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
 
  // The SPA's id. The SPA is registered with this id at the auth-server
  clientId: 'secret',
 
  // set the scope for the permissions the client should request
  // The first three are defined by OIDC. The 4th is a usecase-specific one
  //scope: 'openid your-app-id',
  
  // Or the API scopes  
  scope: 'openid https://your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com/spa-app/read https://your-tenant.onmicrosoft.com/spa-app/write',


  strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false

}

login.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarService } from '../services/nav.service';
import { TranslationService } from '../services/translation.service';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


// Sample: Import the OAuth service with the token validation
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

// Sample: Import configuration module
import { authConfig } from '../auth.config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  imports: [TranslateModule, HttpClientModule]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  currentLang: string = 'es';

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private navbarService: NavbarService,
    private translationService: TranslationService,
    private oauthService: OAuthService 
  ) {
    this.currentLang = this.translationService.getCurrentLang();

    this.translationService.onLangChange().subscribe(event => {
      this.currentLang = event.lang;
    });

    this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
    this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
    
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument().then(() => {
      this.oauthService.tryLogin();
    });
  
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navbarService.hideNavbar();
    this.navbarService.hideSidebar();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.navbarService.displayNavbar();
  }

  usuarioFinal() {
    this.navbarService.displayNavbar();
    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedLang', this.currentLang);
    const consentimiento = sessionStorage.getItem('consentimiento');
    if (consentimiento === 'aceptado') {
      this.router.navigate(['/crear-sesion']);
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/consentimiento-informado']);
    }
  }
  

  switchLanguage(lang: string) {
    this.translationService.changeLang(lang);
  }

  getEspIcon(): string {
    return this.currentLang === 'es' ? 'assets/img/idioma_esp_on.svg' : 'assets/img/idioma_esp_off.svg';
  }

  getEngIcon(): string {
    return this.currentLang === 'en' ? 'assets/img/idioma_ingles_on.svg' : 'assets/img/idioma_ingles_off.svg';
  }

  public login() {
    this.oauthService.initImplicitFlow();
  }
}



Check this for more details about your error.

I tried a sample Angular 18 standalone application for login to Azure AD.

Before deploying the application to Azure Web Apps, make sure that you add your Azure Web App URL under Authentication in Azure AD B2C, as shown below.


Before deploying to Azure Web Apps, add your Azure Web App URL to the redirectUri in auth-config.ts.


auth-config.ts :
import { Configuration, LogLevel } from '@azure/msal-browser';

export const msalConfig: Configuration = {
  auth: {
    clientId: '<clientID>',
    authority: 'https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<B2CpolicyName>',
    redirectUri: '<Azure-webapp-URL>',
    knownAuthorities: ['https://<tenantName>.b2clogin.com/<tenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/<B2CpolicyName>'],
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
    },
  },
};

main.ts :
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { MsalModule, MSAL_INSTANCE, MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { msalConfig } from './app/auth-config';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): PublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
}
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    MsalService,
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

app.component.ts :
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { PublicClientApplication, AuthenticationResult } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { msalConfig } from './auth-config';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  accounts: any[] = [];
  private msalInstance: PublicClientApplication;

  constructor(private msalService: MsalService) {
    this.msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
  }
  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.initializeMsal();
  }
  private async initializeMsal() {
    try {
      await this.msalInstance.initialize();
      this.accounts = await this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('MSAL initialization failed:', error);
    }
  }
  async login() {
    try {
      const response: AuthenticationResult = await this.msalInstance.loginPopup({
        scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access']
      });
      this.accounts = this.msalInstance.getAllAccounts();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login failed:', error);
    }
  }
  logout() {
    this.msalInstance.logout();
  }
}

app.component.html :
<div class="App">
  <header class="App-header">
    <h1>MSAL Angular App</h1>
    <div *ngIf="accounts.length === 0">
      <button (click)="login()">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="accounts.length > 0">
      <p>Welcome</p>
      <button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>


Configure the below startup command in your Azure web app.

pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist/<WebappName>/browser --no-daemon --spa


AzureWbApp Output :


